# Title bar in embedded word document not responsive

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole

I want to embed a word application in a form of my program.  I am using the following code:

```
procedure TAMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  WordApp: Variant;
  WordHandle: THandle;
  TempTitle: string;
begin
  WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  TempTitle := 'Temp - ' + IntToStr(Random(1000000));
  WordApp.Caption := TempTitle;
  WordHandle := FindWindow(nil, PChar(TempTitle));
  WordApp.Visible := True;
  Windows.SetParent(WordHandle, Handle);
  SetWindowPos(WordHandle, 0, Left+20, Top+50, 700, 500, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS);
end;
```

It puts word into my form all right and It seems to works ok.  However  the title bar of the word application is all black and does not respond to mouse clicks.  What is wrong with my code?

Comment: No chance at all of it working with SetParent. Or indeed any other way. Cross process parenting isn't something you can force on other apps. Give it up and find a different design. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683

Comment: Word supports embedding the *editor* as a COM object. (Or it used to, anyway.) It doesn't support embedding the *entire application*. Investigate the former if you want users to edit Word documents without leaving your program.

Answer (score 3):

Having a cross-process parent-child relationship of windows might technically be legal to do, but it is very difficult to manage and would require both processes involved to be aware of this situation. This is explained in detail by Raymond Chen in his blog post [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) Such a cross-process relationship is likely the cause of the problem you are facing.

If you are trying to achieve that your form stays on top of Word, you may implement a workaround based on the `Application.WindowActivate` event. Whenever the Word window is activated you can bring your own form to the top, e.g. using `SetWindowPos`.